# How to show autcompletion from objects created from imported libraries in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm. I imported PIL Image library. I created an image object but is fails to show its corresponding methods/attributes in the autocompletion. Is there any way past this?

[image]

I've tried different interpreters, none work.

```py
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('resources/test.png')

im. #here it does not show autocompleting options
```

Comment: Have you tried typing a couple more letters and then invoking the autocompletion explicitly using Ctrl+Space?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because PyCharm doesn't know exactly the class/type of the `im` object.

If you add a type hint like this:

`im: Image.Image = Image.open('resources/test.png')`

then autocomplete will work.

Comment: Note: if the authors of Pillow indicated the return value's type in the function definition, PyCharm would recognize it and you wouldn't have to use this type hint to get autocompletion.